# BioPython Alphabet Soup

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

Biopython noob here, I'm trying to create a program that uses the Biopython package Alphabet and alphabet module IUPAC to write out the letters of the classes listed to a file called alphabetSoupOuput.txt.

1. ThreeLetterProtein
2. IUPACProtein
3. unambiguous_dna
4. ambiguous_dna
5. ExtendedIUPACProtein
6. ExtendedIUPACDNA

Each group of letters should be written to its single line in the output file and the letters should be separated by commas. The line before each group of letters should contain a label that describes the letters and has a # in the first position of that line, e.g.

Three Letter Protein

Ala, Asx, Cys, ..., Glx

Protein Letters
A, C, D, E, ..., Y

How can I do this?

Comment: I dont know how to extract the letters from the classobj.  any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered on the BioStar StackExchange:

http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/8370/working-with-alphabet-soup

http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/8371/extracting-data-from-classes-in-python